# Is it possible to bind a key shortcut to another key shortcut using Xbindkeys?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, mouse, xbindkeys

What I'm trying to do is to pre-configure a Logitech G602 assigning a specific key combination to each configurable button (G6, G7, G7 etc...) The only way to do that is on Windows (to save the key combinations on the internal memory). But if I set for example Control + Super + 6 to the G6 button and Control + Super + 7 to the G7 button an so on, I can forget about Windows and set binds to every key combination (Control + Super + 6 ...) using Xbindkeys. I have done that with mouses with extra buttons using for example:

```
#Copy
"xdotool key ctrl+C"
   b:8
```

That assigns the copy function to b:8 mouse button. The thing is that this mouse does not work in the same way that other mice do. It is like a keyboard in which I can define the function for every button but in the internal memory. 
This is what I want to do (as an example) but it is not working:

```
#Copy
"xdotool key ctrl+C"
   Control + Super + 6
```

This configuration did not work neither:

```
#Copy
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "Cc""
   Control + Super + 6
```

What I want to do is to basically use a keyboard shortcut to trigger another keyboard shortcut. That way, I can ask for a PC with Windows and do a one-time configuration to the mouse and the assign functions as I want on Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you used `xbindkeys --key` to see what kind of events those buttons send by default?  I don't know if this is the case with your mouse, but I'll note that my Razer keyboard requires an initialization command to be sent before its extra keys report any scancodes at all

Comment: Yes, it detects the key combinations as if I'm typing on the keyboard. The problem is that I can't even bind the keyboard shortcuts using the keyboard it self. Foe example I can't use Control + Super + 6 to execute Control + C Thanks.

Comment: I have also tried with this script on AutoKey assigning it to a key shortcut like Control + Super + 6 `output = system.exec_command("xdotool key ctrl+c") 
keyboard.send_keys(output)`  and it did not work.

Comment: I use `xdotool getactivewindow key --clearmodifiers ctrl+c`.  Otherwise, you're going to be pressing Control and c in addition to the already-pressed Control and Super — Control+Super+c.  Some applications ignore this.  In that case, remove `getactivewindow`

Comment: Thank you! I can't find a way to make it work with Xbindkeys but the I think the problem is with the way Xbindkeys detects the key combinations. The command that you shared is ok and I can easily assign it to a custom shortcut on Keyboard settings on a regular Ubuntu installation and it works just find. I think that the way the key combinations are being detected by `xbindkeys -mk` are causing the issues. Thanks!

Comment: Please don’t [crosspost / multi-post](https://superuser.com/questions/1279629/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-key-shortcut-to-another-key-shortcut-using-xbindkey).

Comment: @eera5607 You may want to create a self-answer (including, if applicable, screenshots of GUI applications) describing the final solution this comment chain has led to.  I'll check back later to delete my comments

Comment: The thing is that at his point the original answer hasn't been answered. There is way to get the results but not with Xbindkeys.

Comment: The content question was "trigger a shortcut with another shortcut".  The title question was "… using Xbindkeys". The former _has_ been answered, while the title question would smell to some like an X-Y problem.  You could probably find an appropriate binding line for `xbindkeys` with the help of `xev` or `xbindkeys --key` (or `--multi-key`), but to me, that feels like a reason we have editable answers.  I'd try to include a few different methods — including a brief description of how to get the key codes — in case other users come along with the same goal but different software